# how to disable certain keys in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have added the following code to my program which, as i understood, must disable alphabets from being entered.
I set the form's KeyPreview property to True,
Next i added this code

```
procedure FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char) ;
```

which was defined as

```
 procedure TFibo.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
  begin
 if Key in ['a'..'z'] then Key := #0
  end;
```

This does not seem to work, as i am able to enter a-z in  the form's edit components; what am i doing wrong?

This is the code for my program

```
 unit Unit1;

 interface

 uses
   Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
   Dialogs, StdCtrls;

 type
   TFibo = class(TForm)
   lblInput: TLabel;
   edtInput: TEdit;
   procedure FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char) ;
 end;

var
  Fibo: TFibo;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure Tfibo.FormKeyPress(Sender:TObject;var Key:char);
begin
  if Key in ['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z'] then
    Key := #0
end;

end.
```

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using? It works in D5 and in D2009.

Comment: Isn't `if not(Key in ['0'..'9', '.']) then` a better option to restrict it to numbers and decimal points only? Else, you'd block e but not ë...

Comment: Instead of edting the question, the correct way to close this question is for you to answer the question yourself with the solution and then accept that answer.

Comment: ... or ask Marjan to kindly turn her comment into an answer that can be accepted.

Comment: @Cosmin @Marjan Yes that would be better still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved. Setting the `OnKeyPress` event in the event tab worked.

Use the Object Inspector of the Form to set the OnkeyPress event. I had written the code but not assigned the event through the Object Inspector. Hence , the event was not registered and it was not firing.

Comment: Please elaborate on this answer, because in it's current form it's not helpful to others. I'd guess most users create the `FormKeyPress` procedure by double-clicking on `OnKeyPress` in Object Inspector, because that automatically creates a procedure with the correct signature *and* selects it as the handler for `OnKeyPress`.

Comment: Please don't "steal" the answer Marjan provided in one of the comments!

Answer (score 3):

Your code works fine in that it blocks 'a' to 'z'.  Perhaps your problem is that it doesn't block upper case characters.  For that you would need:

```
if Key in ['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z'] then
  Key := #0
```

Comment: i specifically said i can enter a-z ; never i mentioned A-Z.

Comment: @sunandan The thing is if you take the steps that you mention then 'a' to 'z' are blocked. Try it in an empty app.

Comment: @sunandan: are you sure the FormKeyPress event handler is hooked up to the Form's event? The code won't do anything if the handler isn't executed because the OnKeyPress property wasn't assigned by the streaming system. Check with the Object Inspector whether the OnKeyPress event of the form actually lists FormKeyPress.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention Delphi version. If you're on a pre-Unicode version, simply make sure you handle both lowercase and uppercase char like this:

```
if Key in ['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z'] then Key := #0;
```

If you're on Unicode delphi, include the `Character` unit and try this:

```
if TCharacter.IsLetter(Key) then Key := #0;
```

Or you can try to use [IsCharAlpha](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647482%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function:

```
if IsCharAlpha(Key) then Key := #0;
```

Comment: @sunandan, you only need the `Character` unit if you're on Unicode Delphi (2009+). On Delphi 7 the first variant works absolutely fine, I actually tried it before posting.

Comment: @sunandan Character unit isn't relevant to Delphi 7. Your main problem is that the problem you describe cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

While reading between the lines, it seems as if you want to allow upper-case letters, but not lowercase. Instead of filtering the lowercase characters, why not set the `CharCase` property of the editbox to `ecUpperCase`? That way, all characters entered are converted to uppercase.